# Creating a box and using COORD from Windows.h to place it in certain parts of the console

Tags: c++, winapi, console

I created a function that takes four parameters as arguments... one for x-coordination, one for y-coordination, one for the width size of the box and one for the height size of the box.

When I try to move the entire box on the win32 console the only part of the box that moves is the top while the rest of the sides remain in place. I was expecting the entire box to move, but there probably is something wrong with my nested loops...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

void Box(int posX, int posY, int sizeWidthX, int sizeHeightY) {
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = posX, coord.Y = posY;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
    for(int w(0); w < sizeWidthX; w++) {
        for(int h(0); h < sizeHeightY; h++) {
            if(w == 0 || h == 0 || w == sizeWidthX - 1 || h == sizeHeightY - 1)
                std::cout<<((char)'\xdb');
            else
                std::cout<<' ';
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    Box(19, 9, 11, 16);
    std::cin.sync();
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't "move" the box, you just draw another one.  You'll have to erase the previous one by writing spaces.

Answer (score -1):

`std::endl` moves the writing position to the left margin on a new line.

Use `std::flush` instead to flush the output buffer, and position the cursor for each line of output.

However you get better control by using the console window API functions for output.

---

An alternative is to use some Windows implementation of the curses library.

Comment: I replaced std::endl with std::flush, it moved a little bit more, but the rest of the box parts are scattered across...

Comment: "and position the cursor for each line of output"

Comment: I did SetConsoleCursorPosition(); on each three of my outputs in the for loops right before the output, not sure if this is what you meant explicitly. The box just became small.